# MarshalDirectiveException in Unity when marshalling int[] to SafeArray

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, marshalling, safearray

Marshalling `int[]` to `SafeArray` seems to behave differently in Unity and in a standalone .NET application.

I have a COM dll that defines an interface

```
[ComImport]
public interface Calibration
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_INT)]
    Array getInputKey();
}
```

In my C# script, either in Unity or in a standalone .NET application, I created my class that inherits from `Calibration`

```
public class MyCalibration : Calibration
{
    private static readonly int[] _inputs = new[] { 0 };

    public void doSomethingElse() 
    {
        // Something
    }

    public Array getInputKey()
    {
        return _inputs;
    }
}
```

Another COM object has a method

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
void setCalibrationInterface([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface), In] Calibration ical);
```

I created an instance of MyCalibration and used it as the argument to the `setCalibrationInterface` method.

```
var myCal = new MyCalibration();
util.setCalibrationInterface(myCal);
```

The `doSomethingElse()` gets called without a problem. However in Unity I got the following exception when `getInputKey()` gets called in the Unity Console:

```
MarshalDirectiveException: The type 'System.Array' layout needs to be Sequential or Explicit
(wrapper native-to-managed) SREYELINKLib.ICalibration.getInputKey(intptr,System.Array&)
UnityEngine.<>c:<RegisterUECatcher>b__0_0(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: For what it's worth, Unity uses Mono underneath, so interop will behave differently between that and .NET.